# Можно ли добавить поддержку Angular в PhpStorm?

Tags: angularjs, веб-программирование, phpstorm

Хотелось бы, что бы директивы, атрибуты и модули как то подсвечивались и, может быть, давали какую то информацию. Сейчас же все ангуляровское светится как "is not allowed here" и горит болотно-зеленым цветом.

 
Спасибо

Comment: Поставьте 10 версию PhpStorm. Потом поставьте плагин `AngularJS`.

Comment: @StepanKasyaneko Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последних версиях PHPStorm есть поддержка AngularJS/Angular2, но необходимо поставить плагин AngularJS из репозитория (Settings | Plugins, Install JetBrains plugin). Кроме того, необходимо наличие соответствующих библиотек в проекте. Для AngularJS это должен быть файл angular.js (отладочная версия, не скрэмблированный и не ужатый). Для Angular2 - соотв. node_modules. Cv/ https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/04/angular-2-workflow-in-webstorm/

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли